# What is the Kernel Maintenance Period for Linux Kernel 5.19 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: kernel

I understand that with the release of Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, support has been provided for the 5.19 kernel and HWE packages.

However, upon checking the Linux long-term kernel versions on the following site, it appears that 5.19 is not a long-term kernel, and version 5.19.17 reached its EOL on October 24, 2022.

https://www.kernel.org/category/releases.html

I'm curious as to whether bug and security patches for the 5.19 kernel supported by 22.04.2 LTS are being handled by Canonical.

Comment: Don't confuse kernel.org EOL with Ubuntu EOL. They will have different dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement kernel, which is part of the 22.04.3 rollout scheduled next month (*the release is actually the ISO release, with currently installed system having received it before ISO release which is the date tracked*) is already visible.

A CLI enquiry will show

```
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04-edge | 6.2.0.25.25~22.04.5   | jammy-proposed   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
```

which is what is replacing the current 5.19.  When that kernel upgrades from the current *proposed*, it'll be available for 22.04 or *jammy* users using the *edge* kernel. It'll then progress for use by normal HWE users & you'll find yourself moving away from 5.19 :)

Ubuntu HWE kernel stacks come from the non-LTS releases, 5.19 from [22.10 which has already had it's EOL warning notices out for awhile now](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/14/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/) and thus the replacement kernel (*which has been viewable in proposed since last week*) soon to be rolled out.

If it's the date that *upstream* stop supporting a kernel, don't be. Ubuntu/Canonical *devs* will backport security fixes during the *supported* life of that kernel for Ubuntu releases; so just apply fixes. You'll get replacements (*like the 6.2 kernel I've shown here*) before the EOL date for Ubuntu support of that package occurs.

To learn more about the HWE or *hardware enablement* stack kernels please refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: I'm involved in QA, thus watch the kernel stack roll out, particularly to see when it appears on the *daily* ISOs and I can start official testing (rather than current ~weekly) of the next cycle... As we're only a ~month away (10 August as per https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906) the release of 6.2 is getting rather close, as is normal & why I check for it now daily.

Comment: While it's possible that 5.19 will still be *supported* after the date when 22.10 is EOL, that is unlikely given it's more work on the Ubuntu community (esp. Canonical staff), but if it happens (*it's happened before with the package rolling out a few days late*) the 5.19 will be supported until its replacement is available & fully rolled out/supported.

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful.

Comment: Just FYI:  the line I pasted was from the output of `rmadison linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04-edge`  ... ie. looking at where the 6.2 kernel (*currently*) can be seen as regards *edge*.. which is where I see it first.. What I really want is it on the 22.04.3 *daily* ISOs, but I don't scan the *manifests* there until I've noticed fully via *edge*.